# User's current playing track

Tags: api, deezer

Is-it possible to get the user's current playing track with Deezer API?

I've tried to use history but it seems to get 1 or 2 minutes before adding the last track... No way to get it real time?

I'm working on iOS app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no real time updates for now in the Deezer API. Using the listening history is the right way to proceed.

If you absolutely need real time, you may use Facebook as an intermediary since they have real time updates for the Deezer users who publish their music activity on Facebook.